# Delete all Storage Files in Backand

Tags: backand

I need to delete all the storage files in the backand...

In Panel > Hosting > Storage Filess -  it's possible to remove only one per.

In Actions it's possible to remove only one per to.

```
files.delete(**filename**);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you delete an app from Backand, it will also delete any stored files for your application. There should be no additional actions needed on your part. If you still have concerns, you can use the command-line interface to point your hosting files at an empty directory, which will have a side effect of deleting the existing files. More information is available at http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/getting_started/hosting/index.html